# Recursive functions multiply

Tags: c#, recursion, multiplication

Can somebody please explain how this recursive function is doing? I'm struggling to understand how you can multiply numbers by using just +

```
        static int Multiply(int x, int y)
        {
            if (y == 1)
            {
                return x;
            }
            else
            {
              return x + Multiply(x, y - 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Multiplication is just adding a value multiple times - e.g. 4 x 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5. This is exactly what the code is doing, decrementing the `y` value each time (`y` represents the number of times to add the same value) and adding the value `x` each time

Comment: This only works for positive non-zero integers. You might want to check the sign of `y` (or use `unsigned int` to force it).

Comment: When you're in struggle - take a piece of paper and try to execute every line manually, line by line.

Answer (score 9):

Remember your basic arithmetic.

```
X * 2 = X + X
X * 3 = X + X + X
```

etc.

So I can factorise `X * 3` as

```
X * 3 = X + (X * 2)
```

so in the function you have:

```
X * Y = X + (X * (Y-1))
```

Therefore

```
X * Y = Multiply(X, Y) =  (X + Multiply(X, Y -1))
```

Which is essentially the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

To explain with an Example...

```
Multiply(5, 4) will call 
Multiply(5, 3) will call 
Multiply(5, 2) will call 
Multiply(5, 1)
```

For each call it will cumulatively add 5 like

```
5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 20
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. For e.g.

```
5 + 5 + 5 = 5 x 3
```

We can simply put this as `Multiply(5, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

it is :

```
x + y(count)-1.

x+(x + (y count-1))
```

**Example :**

```
if x=3 y=4

x+((y-1))

3+(3)=> iteration1
3+(3+3) => iteration 2
3+(3+3+3) => iteration 3



Final => 3+(3+3+3)
Result => 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not the way to go for this requirement given stack limits. Also, evaluate your function with (1, 0) to observe the case where y is less than 1.

Here's a way to "multiply" using addition only with the aid of incrementing which is arguably +/- 1 addition:

```
    static int Multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = 0;

        while (y > 0)
        {
            result += x;
            y--;
        }

        while (y < 0)
        {
            result -= x;
            y++;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That method is not correct because it crashes when you try to multiply by zero.

I wrote a correct method.

```
    public static int Product(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
        else return a + Product(a,b - 1);
    }
```